# Are there books or on-line resources about graphic design for geology?

Tags: geology, reference-request, cartography

Maybe someone knows books that are about graphic design like visual identities, colors, forms, symbols for this industry - Geology?

In short - resources that are about graphic design from Geology point of view?

Answer (score 2):

There is an very detailed ["Digital Cartographic Standard for
Geologic Map Symbolization"](http://ngmdb.usgs.gov/fgdc_gds/geolsymstd/download.php) by the Federal Geographic Data Committee (FGDC) including e.g. color and pattern charts.

Check the main website for the latest version of the Standard, availabe in PostScript format, as pdf, or as ArcGIS10 template.

Answer (score 2):

**I don't think there are any general books on graphic design for geologists.**

However, there are some books about graphical standards for geological maps and sections:

- [FGDC *Digital Cartographic Standard for Geologic Map Symbolization*](http://ngmdb.usgs.gov/fgdc_gds/geolsymstd/download.php)
- [British Geological Survey *Standard Cartographic Index*](http://nora.nerc.ac.uk/3221/1/RR01001.pdf) [PDF]
- [Australian Bureau of Mineral Resources symbols guide](http://www.ga.gov.au/image_cache/GA17066.pdf) [PDF]
- [Shell's *Standard Legend*](http://w3.energistics.org/Shell_Standard_Legend/STANDLEG.PDF) [PDF]

For colour, you might be interested in the [*Munsell Rock Color Chart*](http://www.pantone.com/munsell-rock-color-chart), though it's for describing actual rocks, not making geological maps.

There are lots of books on cartographic design, for example:

- *Cartography: Thematic Map Design*, by Dent et al (2008), ISBN 978-0072943825 — [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0072943823)
- *GIS Cartography: A Guide to Effective Map Design*, by Gretchen Peterson (2014), ISBN 978-1482220674 — [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1482220679)
- The Map as Art: Contemporary Artists Explore Cartography, by Harmon & Clemens (2010), ISBN 978-1568989723 — [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568989725)

Finally, there are [Edward Tufte's amazing books](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/books_be), a must-read for anyone interested in the design of scientific graphics of any kind.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I don't need graphical standards for geological maps and sections, but it's also helpful. But what I really need, you already said that you don't think that there are actually books about making visual identity for geologist/geology company. I think that I will need to use this available information and try to inspire from elements/tools that could be found in geology. For example, if I want to use brown color in visual identity as the main color the source where I get this can be the rocks and so on, just a research in all visual elements, tools, anything that is for geology